# How are identical NSStrings determined in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnotificationcenter

Consider the following code:

```
+ (NSString *)helloString
{
    return @"hello";
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *a = [AppDelegate helloString];
    NSString *b = [AppDelegate helloString];
    NSLog(@"%@", a == b ? @"yes" : @"no");
    abort();
}
```

On my machine the result is always "yes". Does it mean that the NSString literal `@"hello"` is **always** the same "object" in Objective-C runtime?

Actually my original purpose is to use an uniquely identifiable object to bind in `NSNotification`'s `postNotificationName:object:` method. I plan to use a NSString literal to act as the object. Is it safe/recommended to do so?

Comment: If you compare two objects with `==` that means that the two objects are in fact the same object.

Comment: String literals are "interned" (or whatever term you choose) and even though you "create" two different instances of the same character sequence, iOS may figure it out and give you the same pointer twice.

Comment: IIRC, it's an implementation detail (an optimization), not a guaranteed behavior. Don't rely on it.

Comment: But note in the above case that there really is only one instance of `@"hello"`.  So comparing equal would be not only expected but required.

Comment: You don't make it clear what you mean by "a string literal".  If it's the same literal in the same line of code then it will always be the same object.  If you mean two different copies of `@"hello"` in different modules then it will *probably* be the same object, but not really guaranteed.

Comment: @HotLicks I was wondering whether the same line of code `@"hello"` would ever yield different NSString objects but you already explained well. thx.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way that the *same* line could yield different objects would be with some weird scenarios with precompiled libraries where the module containing the line is actually included in the app twice, eg, once in the main app and once in the library.  (But their probably are better ways to obtain the identifier object you seek -- though none come to mind just now.)

Comment: Note that if you want an identifier pointer to associate with a class, you can use `[MyClass class]` to get a pointer to the class object for MyClass.  This is subject to the slight weirdness with libraries as I described above for strings, but otherwise should be at least as reliable as a literal string containing the class name, plus you can execute the expression different places in your code and get the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the compiler implementation, which in theory could change from time to time, so it is not reliable. If you need to make sure that the NSString pointer is always the same, you should use a constant.

```
const NSString* kSomeConstantName = @"ConstantValue";
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, NSString literals were guaranteed to be unique within a translation unit, and were often unique even between translation units in practice. The current documentation no longer makes this claim as far as I know, and the Clang docs recommend against relying on it.

If you want a string that's guaranteed to always be the same object, you can simply assign a string to a global constant. All references to that constant will *definitely* yield the same object.

With regard to NSNotification, though, I wouldn't use such a string as the object. The semantics of NSNotification say the the object argument should be the object that triggered the notification — where it conceptually "comes from." Other information associated with the notification would make more sense in the user info dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[a isEqualToString: b] compares two strings a and b, and returns YES if the contents is the same. This works if they are the same object, or different objects, or one is an NSString and one is an NSMutableString, or one is one of the many classes that behave like strings. If a is nil the result is NO, if a is not nil but b is nil you get a crash.

Comparing strings with a == b is interesting: If a and b are both nil the result is YES, one nil but not the other returns NO. If a and b are the same string because you have the same string literal or the same NSString object assigned to a and b, the result is YES. In your example, the "helloString" method always returns the same literal. Not just a literal with the same characters, but the same literal.

If you use literals with the same characters, they may or may not be the same. No guarantees. If you use the copy method, the result may be the same as the original or not. No guarantees. All in all, == or != for NSString is not very useful. It's only useful to compare nil vs. not nil, or if you know exactly which string was assigned.

BTW >=, >, <=, < give undefined behaviour if the strings are not the same, so they are completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following Code:

```
[a isEqualToString:b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your case `@"hello"` is always returned same pointer as mostly all language including objective c use [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)  for `string literals` which means for same `string literal` it reruns single object.

But this is not the case which is always true means two strings with same characters may have different references if you allocate them differently by `alloc` keyword.
So always use `isEqualToString:` if you need to check string equality for its contents.`==` is used for reference equality(locations in memory) which may or may not different for same contents strings.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that the NSString literal @"hello" is always the same "object" in Objective-C runtime?

I wouldn't count on it being true in all cases. Strings should be compared with `-isEqualToString:`.

> Actually my original purpose is to use an uniquely identifiable object to bind in NSNotification's postNotificationName:object: method.

That seems like a misuse of the API. In most cases, you should just pass the object that's posting the notification.